# How do I get the time difference when the values are stored in strings?

Tags: c#, time

I need to find to the time difference between two values, but the values are in a string format and not in a DateTime Object. I can use the TimeSpan class only if it is a DateTime Object.

Moreover it is in a YYYY/MM/DD hh:mm:ss.zz format. I can extract the time part alone, that's not a problem. But I am unable to find the difference all the same.

Comment: you can use `ParseExact` with a format string of `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss`

Comment: It also depends on the current culture of the current thread.
So it always better to format the dates to universal sortable formats before manipulating them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.Parse("[datestring here]")` then use the .Subtract() from the object to calculate the difference.

```
var d1 = DateTime.Parse("");
var d2 = DateTime.Parse("");

var totalMinures = d1.Subtract(d2).TotalMinutes
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you have datetime string in a particular format, you can use DateTime.ParseExact to change the string to Datetime and use the normal operations on it.